# 24h format in the x axis along a whole week

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to show the evolution of a variable (var) along a week. My data is in a text file (available [here](https://cloud.cttc.upc.edu/owncloud/index.php/s/pVbAzFb4KLDkgk2)). The time data is given in hours as shown in the following plot.

[image]

Do you know how to show the time in 24 hours format in the x-axis? I mean following a sequence like 0 6 12 18 0 6 12 18 ... and so on.

I tried to use text labels from the same file (using `xtick=data` and `xticklabels from table={data.dat}{time}`). For doing this, it would require to add a new column in the file with the desired format. For the moment I tried by using the same "time" column. However the dataset is too large and the resulting x axis is unreadable (the image is also in the link).

I also tried using `x filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1-floor(#1/24)*24}}`. Unfortunately the different days overlay each other. I guess this is because the filtered data are floats instead of text (the image is also in the link).

Here is my code,

```
\documentclass{standalone}                                                                                                                                                 
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}                                                                                                                                                 
\begin{document}                                                                                                                                                           
\begin{tikzpicture}                                                                                                                                                        
\begin{axis}[                                                                                                                                                              
  ylabel=var,                                                                                                                                                              
  xlabel=week hour,                                                                                                                                                        
  xmin=0, xmax=168,                                                                                                                                                        
  %xtick=data,                                                                                                                                                             
  %xticklabels from table={data.dat}{time}                                                                                                                                 
  %x filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1-floor(#1/24)*24}},                                                                                                                     
]                                                                                                                                                                          
\addplot[] table [x=time,y=var,col sep=space] {./data.dat};                                                                                                                
\end{axis}                                                                                                                                                                 
\end{tikzpicture}                                                                                                                                                          
\end{document}
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved in two steps.

#### Specify tick labels (interval)

You can specify the tick positions with `xtick={<min>,<step>,...,<max>}`, and parse the tick labels by giving the expression to `xticklabel`. Since you give `xmin` and `xmax` explicitly, you can set the tick locations "semi-automatic" with `xtick={\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},<step>,...,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}}`. This way, if you change `xmin` and/or `xmax` you don't have to edit `xtick` as well.

#### Parse the value to wanted format

Here it uses `\pgfmathparse` to parse the expression, and `\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}` to print the number without decimals, which is essential to actually get the label showing. `\pgfmathresult` holds the value from the last invoked `\pgfmathparse`.

#### Example

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  width=15cm,
  ylabel=var,
  xlabel=week hour,
  xmin=0,
  xmax=168,
  xtick={0,6,...,168},
  xticklabel={\pgfmathparse{int(mod(\tick,24))}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}
]                                                                                                                                                                          
\addplot[mark=none] table [x=time,y=var,col sep=space] {./data.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

I added a `width=15cm` to fit the all the tick labels on the x axis. I would consider to only include tickmarks at every 0 and 12 hours, just to make the axis less cluttered. Optionally you can add a minor tick mark at every 6 hours by specifying `minor x tick num=1`, which means there will be *one* minor tick mark between each major tick mark.

With `xtick={0,12,...,168}` and `minor x tick num=1`:

[image: Output 2]

Comment: you can just use `int(mod(\tick,24))` function